# Defining function works weird in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm on studying react-redux now.
There was something weird situation, and it took my whole day hours.

this is a common way in many tutorials.
But it didn't work in my code.
In detail, didn't pass the event to props.

```
const VisibleFilterList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterList);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateFilter : (ev) => dispatch(setFilter(ev.target.value))
    }
};
```

After a lot of digging this problem, I just changed the arrow function to a normal function. Then it works!....?!?!

```
const VisibleFilterList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps2)(FilterList);

function mapDispatchToProps2(dispatch) {
    return {
        updateFilter : (ev) => dispatch(setFilter(ev.target.value))
    }
}
```

Even the functions are having same return method. And I wonder why the arrow function doesn't work. In many tutorials, using arrow function looks more common. Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `variable` declaration will not lifting up,but `function` declaration does.the code below `mapDispatchToProps` is undefined,because not declared an variable `mapDispatchToProps` before `connect()` called.except `function` lifting up,the `import` directive also does lifting declaration up.the variable declaration keywords is strange,if you want to know see Variable Declaration section.

### Change the declaration order

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
    updateFilter : (ev) => dispatch(setFilter(ev.target.value))
   }
};
const VisibleFilterList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterList);
```

### Test

```
describe('decalration lifting up', () => {

    test('constants not lifting up', () => {
        const foo = bar;
        const bar = () => {};

        var fuzz = buzz;
        const buzz = 'buzz';

        expect(foo).toBeUndefined();
        expect(fuzz).toBeUndefined();//not 'buzz'
    });

    test('variable not lifting up', () => {
        let foo = bar;
        let bar = () => {};

        expect(foo).toBeUndefined();
    });

    test('function lifting up', () => {
        let foo = bar;

        function bar() {};

        expect(foo).toEqual(expect.any(Function));
    });
});
```

### Variable Declaration

```
//I think these variable declarations,first allocate fuzz & buzz memory
//，then execute assignment.so const fuzz=buzz can works
//,because buzz be found in memory
const fuzz = buzz;//undefined
const buzz = 'buzz';

//in this case,buzz has not allocate memory,so it can't be found by assignment.
const fuzz = buzz;//throws an exception: fuzz is not defined
```

Comment: The `const` declaration is "hoisted" and *mapDispatchToProps* is initialised to *undefined*, but assignment of the arrow function isn't, otherwise the OP would get a reference error. ;-) Oh, well spotted by the way.

Comment: I'll test it,if it does,I'll update my answer.thanks

Comment: @RobG I've updated my answer,please tell me if I have something wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I fully understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the arrow function to

```
mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateFilter : (ev) => dispatch(setFilter(ev.target.value))
    }
};
```

This answer is based on the visible code that you shared, if you show more code I may have to update this answer.

Regardless, get used to using the arrow functions because it is the future.

Comment: You need to explain why the OP has their issue and what you changed to fix it (assuming that it does fix it, which likely it doesn't).

Comment: That's a good point, I will definitely keep that in mind for future answers, thank you for bringing that to my attention!